# typesafe config: define global configurations to be used in "sub-configs "

Tags: configuration, config, typesafe

I have a large `config file`and I would like to avoid writing duplicates.

example:

```
shared_part: {
}

cof1 {
 . . . 
 subconf {
   shared: shared_part
 }
}

cof2 {
 . . . 
 subconf {
   shared: shared_part
 }
}
```

I tried to import the `shared_par`by simply writing it as it is and by `${shared_part}`but none worked.

how would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend against big config files if the config blocks are meant to be used in different contexts, as I suppose your `conf1` and `conf2` do.

Define all your common properties in a `sharedPart.conf` (the naming is for the sake of your example), and the others in `conf1.conf` and `conf2.conf`.
Afterwards, in order to use the common properties within the last two files, add the following to the head of the files:

`include "sharedPart.conf"`

Comment: your answer is partial working, in order to use the `sharedPart` in all `subConf`, I hade to `include "sharedPart.conf"` in all `cof`. But the good part is that it works as I wanted. thank you (multumesc) Bianca.

Comment: If you still put them under the same file, indeed. If you have them into separate files, you need to include it in all the files. Glad that I could help.